# Safari not rendering px values correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have the following super simple HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div style="height: 4px; background-color: hotpink; margin-bottom: 2px;"></div>
        <div style="height: 4px; background-color: hotpink; margin-bottom: 2px;"></div>
        <div style="height: 4px; background-color: hotpink; margin-bottom: 2px;"></div>
        <div style="height: 4px; background-color: hotpink; margin-bottom: 2px;"></div>
        <div style="height: 4px; background-color: hotpink; margin-bottom: 2px;"></div>
        <div style="height: 4px; background-color: hotpink; margin-bottom: 2px;"></div>
        <div style="height: 4px; background-color: hotpink; margin-bottom: 2px;"></div>
        <div style="height: 4px; background-color: hotpink; margin-bottom: 2px;"></div>
        <div style="height: 4px; background-color: hotpink; margin-bottom: 2px;"></div>
        <div style="height: 4px; background-color: hotpink; margin-bottom: 2px;"></div>
        <div style="height: 4px; background-color: hotpink; margin-bottom: 2px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

These are the output from Safari and Chrome respectively:

[image: pink lines with non uniform distribution]

[image: pink lines with uniform distribution]

For some reason the line gap between the divs are not consistent on Safari? Can someone please explain this?

### Edit

I'm playing around with the positioning and various CSS, and using the inspector shows the div with size `3px` even though I specified `4px`. Does this mean anything?

[image]

Comment: Can't repro on Safari 14.0.1 (16610.2.11.51.8) (Big Sur). Definitely caused by antialiasing. You could try a CSS `#root { transform: translateZ(0px); }` to see if it fixes it, but finding why antialiasing has to kick in in the first place would be better for you.

Comment: Surprisingly, running the live snippet produces the correct result! Just tried adding the `translateZ` CSS and I still get the same issue. I agree, the antialiasing has been causing me a lot of issues, this was just a minimum reproducible example. How would I go about finding out why the antialiasing is kicking in?

Comment: Not sure, even running your code as a standalone file doesn't reproduce it for me. If you try `console.log( document.querySelectorAll("#root > div")[3].getBoundingClientRect().top )`, does this output some floating number? Also, do you have any extensions that could be running on that page and messing with font-size or default margins etc. What if you remove the <meta> tag? What is your Safari version? Are you running this on a retina display?

Comment: Yes, running the query does produce a floating number. I don't think I have any extensions, and even if I do, other sites are working perfectly fine, Safari just tripping up on my site? My svgs are getting trimmed etc. This is my Safari version `Version 14.0 (15610.1.28.1.9, 15610)`. Nope, not a retina display, happening on both built in MacBook display and external display. Getting the same result after removing the `<meta>` tag

Comment: It seems the latest Safari on Catalina is full of new bugs... If the translate trick didn't work and since the BigSur version works fine, I'm afraid I can't help more... You may want to open a bug report at https://bugs.webkit.org/ Ps: it should have been an integer value, the fact you have a float value here means that something above has a floating height, which pushes everything on non-integer values, and to avoid antialiasing through blurring, they round the coords, apparently badly since they could have chosen floor or ceil to avoid this...

Comment: Yep. You're right. I've just tested the same piece of code on Big Sur. Everything is fine, and the query outputs an integer value. I'll try to figure out why the Catalina is behaving strangely.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're having an anti-aliasing issue.
Could be caused by zooming in or having a style applied that causes scale.

Is this happening on Mac or Mobile? Rotating the screen on mobile safari can cause it to zoom unintentionally.

Have you tried changing your viewport meta from

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

To

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: This is happening on a Mac. It's happening even without zooming in. Just tried changing the viewport, same thing :(

Comment: Can't replicate the issue on Safari Version 14.0 (15610.1.28.1.9, 15610). 
Could you try an example with absolute positioned elements and see if it produces the same issue

Comment: Yep, same result.